# Optimal Facebook Graph API / FQL query to get list of albums with cover photo

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm currently doing a graph api call to get a list of a person's photo albums and then an additional call to query the id of those albums to get the cover photo url of each. Is there a way to do this all in one query?

Comment: [The accepted answer on this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170567/facebook-php-how-to-get-album-cover-photo) contains the FQL statement you need.

Comment: you still have to do a second call with the accepted answer on that post. their question was to get the cover photo of an album given its album id. I need a query in either graph of fql to get a list of albums AND their cover photos in one query.

Comment: Just remove the `WHERE album_id = XXX` from the sub query - it'll just return for all albums...

Comment: `SELECT pid, src_small FROM photo WHERE pid in (SELECT cover_pid FROM album WHERE owner=user_id)`

Comment: thank you. do you know how to do this with the graph api?

Comment: You can easily execute FQL statements though the graph API using a syntax like this - `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=YPUR_FQL_HERE`. You'll have to url encode the query string first though.